# Longest common substring Algorithm O(n*m) brute force

Tags: algorithm, substring

I'm looking at the algorithm on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

They use dynamic programming, which gives them a time of O(nm). However, can't the same time complexity be achieved with a brute force algorithm? I am doing a homework question, to find this algorithm in O(n*m) time, where n and m are the string lengths.

For a string A and string B, I check if A[i] equals any element in B. If it does equal some B[j], then check if A[i + 1] equals to B[j + 1], then if A[i + 2] = in B[i + 2] and so forth until no more match or end of string. If it is the no match case, then continue checking A[i] in B starting from the last element we checked in B. We repeat this process for every A element, while storing the start and end index for the max substring found so far. This algorithm appears to be O(n*m). If I'm not wrong about this, is there any reason why this approach is not used?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your algorithm correctly, then I believe it is wrong.

Let `A = "abac"` and `B = "ababac"`. Then, with `i = 0`, we see that the strings match at `j = 0`. So we start matching, and fail at `j = 3` since `b != c`. So we start matching at `j = 3`, but fail immediately since `b != a` (note that we don't start at `j = 2` since we successfully matched `a = a` there). We would then conclude the longest substring is `aba`, which is incorrect.

Comment: Ah okay, you are right. I guess in that case, I would make A[i] check the next B element B[j + 1] instead of the last checked element. However, that would be n^2 iterations per A element then, giving me O(n^3), if n = m. Wiki way it is. Thanks.